# Global variable life in Javascript - destroyed on a reload?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

(I am learning Javascript)

Problem: A page I am working on has 2 views, a data entry view with a textbox and a data rendering view. There is a `a href src="currentpage#"` link that switches between the 2 views. In order to transmit data from view to view, the javascript parses it from the current HTML and pushes it into the correct form for the other view. This is *ugly* and I want to refactor it out, ideally into some sort of global where it can be neatly rendered down into the view on command (I'm refactoring the code base to a point where I can AJAX it from a server).

However, I am not certain about scoping rules and variable life in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(if I understand your question correctly)*

If you're just using **internal** links (`a href='#myanchor'` for example) your javascript variable will not go out of scope because your page won't actually get reloaded.

Just don't link to `a href='currentpage.html#myanchor'` as *that* will get your page reloaded.

Note that normal (level) scoping rules do still apply!

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies, or hide the variable in an higher iframe (IMHO better idea, since cookies are sent back and forth between the server and client).